# Editing widgets in another Kivy screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to get the nickname from the intro screen and then build the chat screen using this nickname in a label. However, I can't get my function to work with ids properly.

.kv:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

Screens:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    Intro
    Chat

<Intro>:
    id: intro
    TextInput:
        id: intro_text
        ...
    Button:
        ...
        on_press: root.intro_bt_press()

<Chat>:
    name: "main"
    Label:
        id: lb_name
```

.py:

```
from kivy import require
require("1.9.1")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder

nick = ""

class Chat(Screen):
    lb_name.text = "Chat with {}".format(nick)

class Intro(Screen):
    global nick
    def intro_bt_press(self):
        nick = intro_text.text
        App.get_running_app().root.current = "main"

class Screens(ScreenManager):
    pass

Screens = Builder.load_file("chat.kv")

class Chat(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screens

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Chat().run()
```

So when the button is pressed, I want to get the text from TextInput, switch to the main screen and format the label on that screen with the text. I can't assign the text to the variable "nick" because it says that it's not defined. And the same goes for lb_name, but I can't even get past the first error. What am I missing before the id to tell Python, where in the kv file to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id`s assigned in `kv` are available in the `ids` 
property. if you want to access the widgets in your Python file, use something like `self.ids['intro_text'].text` in `intro_bt_press`.

However, the desired behaviour can be achieved just using the `kv` language:

This is `chat.kv`:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<Screens@ScreenManager>:

Screens:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    Intro
    Chat

<Intro@Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: intro_text
        Button:
            on_press:
                root.manager.get_screen('main').ids.lb_name.text = root.ids.intro_text.text
                root.manager.current = "main"

<Chat@Screen>:
    name: "main"
    Label:
        id: lb_name
```

And this is `chat.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App

class ChatApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```